# Selenium RC : Page is not loading compeletelly

Tags: selenium, loading, page-break

When I run my selenium rc script page is not loading completely because of change in the urls.

Earlier it was working fine when url was something link this

```
https://testersworld.com/
```

But now it changed to (updated the URL in the script before run)

```
https://testersworld.com/#login
```

Because of which when I run the script browser launches with specified url but fails to displayed login popup.

How to handle this `https://testersworld.com/#login` which gives login pop after page load. I used all methods of wait.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("https://testersworld.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("https://testersworld.com/");
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

or
select locator on login page (e.g. input login(e-mail ) field):

```
String cssLocator=..blablabla...;
```

and use *fluentWait* mechanism:

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;


fluentWait(By.cssSelector(cssLocator));
```